R plotly - Colorscale in colorbar is not the same as in plot
I have a scatter plot in R plotly where I want to color the markers on a fixed scale from 1 to 20, where 1 = dark green and 20 = dark red. Since this will be part of a Shiny app, I want to be able to filter the data while maintaining this specific colorscale. I am using the cmin and cmax values for this.
The following example works, but the colorbar is completely wrong:
library(plotly)

data = data.frame(x = seq(1, 20),
                  y = seq(5, 24),
                  z = seq(1, 20)) %>%
  filter(z > 4 & z < 10)

fig <- plot_ly(data) %>%
  add_trace(
    data,
    type = 'scatter',
    mode='markers',
    x = ~x,
    y = ~y,
    color = ~z,
    colors = "RdYlGn",
    marker=list(
      reversescale = T,
      cmin = 1,
      cmax = 20,
      colorbar=list(
        borderwidth = 5,
        outlinewidth = 5,
        title=list(text='abc')
      )
    )
  )

fig

Result:

There are several issues here.

The colorbar is not reversed as in the plot. It says that lower values are red and higher values are green, when the opposite is true.
The colorbar shows that the values vary from dark red to dark green within the range of the plot. However, all values in the plot are in the light green range.
The colorbar does not go from 1 to 20, which would be my preferred option so that the colorbar does not change everytime a filter is applied.
Possibly unrelated, but the colorbar options also do not do anything - title and outline width are not as specified.

Any help is highly appreciated!

You can accomplish this if you move the color = ~z and colors/colorscale arguments inside of the markers = list() arugment.
One thing is that once you do this, it seems like Plotly will only let you use certain color palettes and "RdYlGn" is not among them. I found this discussion that lists the available color palettes that will work if you set the code up this way.
plot_ly(data,
  type = 'scatter',
  mode='markers',
  x = ~x, 
  y = ~y,
  marker = list(
    color= ~z,
    colorscale = "Viridis",
    cmax = 20,
    cmin = 0,
    colorbar=list(
      title='abc',
      borderwidth = 5,
      outlinewidth = 5
    ),
    reversescale = T
  )
)


This is the old answer that only reformats the colorbar
fig <- plot_ly(data) %>%
  add_trace(
    data,
    type = 'scatter',
    mode='markers',
    x = ~x,
    y = ~y,
    color = ~z,
    colors = "RdYlGn",
    color = list(reversescale = T)) %>%
  colorbar(
        limits = c(0, 20),
        borderwidth = 5,
        outlinewidth = 5,
        title=list(text='abc')
      )


Thanks a lot, this works. However, I am simply astounded. This is not at all what the official documentation says I should do. The reference for colorbar literally lists it under marker.colorbar and multiple plot examples suggest that you use it the way I did. How did you know to do it like this?

Also, you are defining "color" twice. Should that not overwrite each other? What kind of weird syntax am I looking at here? (It's also not working as intended with my scattergeo plot, so I have a feeling that this is not the whole truth.)

Ok, upon further checking this is indeed not working at all, except for the part where calling colorbar as a function allows me to edit the values of the colorbar correctly. But color = list(reversescale = T) does not work.

I'm so sorry about that. I was very focused on the colorbar formatting and somehow missed that the colorbar order was not correct. I’ve updated the answer above. Let me know if that works!

Thanks for your effort, but that is not what I want - I do not want Viridis, I want one of the other supplied colorscales and it's not working for them. That was actually the point of my question. I figured it out now using custom color palettes, but that answer is really not that satisfactory and it seems to me that this is simply a bug.
